# Switch command pages in delphi

Tags: delphi, command, delphi-7

First of all, i would like to apologise in advance for how bad the title may be, but i really need your help.

First of all, let me explain you what i meam by switch command pages: 
Let's guess that we have 2 buttons. Then we command button 1 on click to do:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Showmessage('Hi');
end;

end.
```

Ok, now when i click only once on button2, i want button1 to do on click something else (Change the commands of button1), for example `showmessage ('My name is Monster')`.

I don't know how this method is called, but it is used in some game making applications as the following (not like that, but similar):

```
**When** button1 clicked then showmessage ('Hi');
**When** button2 clicked **Then** button1 switch page 2--> Showmessage('My name is')
**When** button3 clicked **Then** button1 switch page 1--> Showmessage('Hi')
```

I hope i've helped you enough to understand what i asked, thanks

Comment: Have you tried making some panels and hiding and showing them from code?

Comment: You can assign an event handler at run time. In 'Button2Click', run `Button1.Onclick=Button1_2ndClick` where 'Button1_2ndClick' is a method of the TNotifyEvent signature. .. in case this is what you are asking..

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by  Sertac Akyuz just simply can assign another event to your button.

An overdrawn example could be:

```
unit DynamicEvents;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;


type
  TNotifyClass=Class
    Constructor Create(const msg:String);overload ;
    Constructor Create(EV:TNotifyEvent);overload;
    Procedure NotifyEvent(Sender:TObject);
  private
    FMessage:String;
    FNotifyEvent:TNotifyEvent;
  End;

  TNotifyList=Class
    Constructor Create(arr:Array of String);
    Destructor Destroy;override;
    private
    FList:TList;
    FLastAccessedIndex:Integer;
    function GetEvent(Index: Integer): TNotifyEvent;
    public
    Property Events[Index:Integer]:TNotifyEvent read GetEvent; default;
    Procedure Add(NC:TNotifyClass);
    published

    Property LastAccessedIndex:Integer read FLastAccessedIndex;
  End;

  TForm6 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    FNotifyList:TNotifyList;
    procedure FormCloseEV(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form6: TForm6;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TNotifyList }

procedure TNotifyList.Add(NC: TNotifyClass);
begin
  Flist.Add(NC);
end;

constructor TNotifyList.Create(arr: array of String);
var
 i:Integer;
begin
   FList := TList.Create;
   FLastAccessedIndex := -1;
   for I := Low(arr) to High(arr) do
     FList.Add(TNotifyClass.Create(arr[i]));
end;

destructor TNotifyList.Destroy;
var
 i:Integer;
begin
   for I := 0 to Flist.Count -1  do
     TNotifyClass(FList[i]).Free;
   Flist.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TNotifyList.GetEvent(Index: Integer): TNotifyEvent;
begin
   if (Index>=0) and (Index<Flist.Count) then
    begin
      FLastAccessedIndex := Index;
    end
   else
    begin
      if Flist.Count>0 then
        begin
         FLastAccessedIndex := 0;
        end
      else
        begin
         FLastAccessedIndex := -1;
        end;
    end;
    if FLastAccessedIndex >- 1 then Result := TNotifyClass(FList[FLastAccessedIndex]).NotifyEvent;
end;



procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Button2.OnClick := FNotifyList[FNotifyList.LastAccessedIndex + 1];
end;

{ TNotifyClass }

constructor TNotifyClass.Create(const msg: String);
begin
   FMessage := msg;
end;
constructor TNotifyClass.Create(EV:TNotifyEvent);
begin
   FNotifyEvent := EV;
end;

procedure TNotifyClass.NotifyEvent(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if Assigned(FNotifyEvent) then FNotifyEvent(Sender)
   else Showmessage(FMessage);
end;

procedure TForm6.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutDown := true;
  FNotifyList:=TNotifyList.Create(
                ['Message 1'
                ,'Message 2'
                ,'Message 3'
                ,'Message 4'
                ,'Message 5'
                ,'Message 6'
                ,'Message 7'
                ,'Message 8'
                ,'Message 9'
                ,'Message 10']
                );
  FNotifyList.Add(TNotifyClass.Create(FormCloseEV));
end;

procedure TForm6.FormCloseEV(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if MessageDLG('Close',mtConfirmation,[mbyes,mbCancel],0)=idYes then Close;

end;


procedure TForm6.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FNotifyList.Free;
end;

end.
```

Comment: @user2276109 - If you want to program, you should get used to writing code :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with a TActionList:

1. Put 3 TButtons on your form
2. Put a TActionList on your form.
3. Add a new action for each command you want your Button1 to execute.
4. If you want to start at design time, **designate Action1 in the Action
   property of Button1.** This can also be done at runtime.
5. Button2: in its onClick event, assign **action2 to button 1.**
6. Button3: in its onClick event, assign **action3 to button 1.**

   **Etc.**

Your form's code will look something like this:

**//action.onExecute's:**

```
procedure TForm1.Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
   DoStuff;
end;

procedure TForm1.Action2Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoMoreStuff
end;

procedure TForm1.Action3Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
 DoOtherStuff;
end;
```

**//Button.onClick's:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Button1.Action:=Action2;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.Action:=Action3;
end;
```

**//Your 'commands':**

```
procedure TForm1.DoStuff;
begin
  showmessage('hi');
end;

procedure TForm1.DoMoreStuff;
begin
 showMessage('red');
 Self.Color:=clRed;
end;

procedure TForm1.DoOtherStuff;
begin
  showMessage('black');
  self.Color:=clBlack;
end;
```

Comment: the problem is that whenever i do that, it changes the caption of the button

Comment: You can change the caption via the action, which has a caption property that will be reflected in the button. If you want the caption never to change, set the caption to all the actions to be the same. Or try changing the caption of the button to be what you like in the action.onExecute itself : Button1.Action:=Action2; Button1.Caption:='Whatever you like'. My answer is essentially the same as what Bummi answered and Sertac Akyuz told you in the comments - just that actions make that easier - less code, action handles everything.